# Mark One and Only One Record as "Primary"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a genealogy application and I'm trying to figure out on aspect of my database model.

I have a table for people:

```sql
create table person (
  id int unsigned not null primary key
)
```

And I have a table for names:

```sql
create table name (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  person_id int unsigned not null,
  first_name varchar(191),
  last_name varchar(191),
  foreign key (person_id) references person (id)
)
```

A person can have multiple names because sometimes they have different names in different censuses and other records.

But a person also has one particular name which we should display by default.

---

My first thought was to add a `primary` column to the table `name`:

```sql
create table person (
  id int unsigned not null primary key
)

create table name (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  person_id int unsigned not null,
  first_name varchar(191),
  last_name varchar(191),
  `primary` tinyint(1) not null default 0,
  foreign key (person_id) references person (id)
)
```

This has a data-integrity issue. Multiple names that belong to a single person could have the `primary` flag set.

---

Another way I thought of was to add a `primary_name_id` column to the `person` table. This could link back to the primary name in the `name` table:

```sql
create table person (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  primary_name_id int unsigned default null,
  foreign key (primary_name_id) references name (id)
)

create table name (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  person_id int unsigned not null,
  first_name varchar(191),
  last_name varchar(191),
  foreign key (person_id) references person (id)
)
```

This also has has an integrity issue. `primary_name_id` might point to a name row that belongs to a different person. Also, it requires the `primary_name_id` column to be nullable because when a person is first created he has no names yet.

---

The third way I thought about doing this is to include duplicates of the "name" fields in the person record:

```sql
create table person (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  first_name varchar(191),
  last_name varchar(191),
)

create table additional_name (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  person_id int unsigned not null,
  first_name varchar(191),
  last_name varchar(191),
  foreign key (person_id) references person (id)
)
```

This doesn't seem like an ideal solution either. Similar kinds of data are being stored in two places. Also changing a person's primary name would require a bit of work. I'd have to insert a new additional_name, update the person, and delete an old additional name.

---

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about a `current_name_id` in the `person` table?

Comment: The suggestion by @ceejayoz sounds good to me.  Just keep track of the current name id in a single place.  Anyway, maybe it should not be the responsibility of the `name` table to keep track of the current name.  Rather, each person should be keeping track of this.

Comment: @ceejayoz, if I understand correctly, that's like my second proposed solution. I called my column `primary_name_id`. That's actually how my database is set up at the moment. My concern is that `primary_name_id` could point to a name that belongs to the wrong person, so I wondered if there were any other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method is basically the right way.  But, you want to be sure that the name is for the person.  So:

```
create table person (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  primary_name_id int unsigned default null,
  foreign key (id, primary_name_id) references name (person_id, id)
);

create table name (
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  person_id int unsigned not null,
  first_name varchar(191),
  last_name varchar(191),
  foreign key (person_id) references person (id),
  unique (person_id, id);
);
```

The `unique` constraint is a bit of redundancy, but it let's you ensure that the values match across the two tables -- appropriately.